# Answers won't show up as correct in python vocab test?

Tags: python-3.x

This is the coding that I have so far. The basic concept is that you have a separate file to type in the answers and then the program accesses the separate file and draws information from it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

#Vocabulary/translation quiz

import os
import random

keep_adding=input("Would you like to start a new quiz ? If yes, press \"S\" : ")
with open("data.txt","a") as f: #look for the file data.txt for the questions
    while keep_adding=="S": #ongoing action to look for the answer
        word=input("Enter a word : ")
        translation=input("And its translation : ") 
        f.write("{0},{1},\n".format(word,translation))
        keep_adding=input("To continue, press \"O\" : ")


#in case the file doesn't exist, we create one :
with open("data.txt","a") as f:
    pass

os.system('clear')
print("* * * QUIZ STARTS! * * *") #this shows the quiz has started after 'o' input

with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    question = [line.split(",") for line in f]
i = 0
score = 0 #variables
while i<len(question):
    num = random.randint(0,len(question)-1) #creates random question from the list
    print("\nQuestion number", i+1,": \nWhat is the translation for", question[num][0], "?")
    answer = input("Answer :")
    if (answer == str(question[num][1])):
        print("Congratulations! That's the good answer!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong. The correct answer was :",question[num][1]) #just tells you the wrong answer
    i += 1

if len(question)==0:
    print("\nThe file is empty. Please add new words to start the quiz !\n")
else:   
    if i>1:
        qu_pl = "questions"
    else:
        qu_pl = "question"
    if score>1:
        sc_pl = "answers"
     else:
        sc_pl = "answer"
    print("\n RESULTS :\n ",i, qu_pl,", ",score,"correct ",sc_pl," \n"\
    ," --> Your score is : ",score*100/i,"% !\n")
```

The basic concept is that you have a separate file to type in the answers and then the program accesses the separate file and draws information from it.

My problem; the program accesses this file and successfully gains the information but when you actually try to run the program with multiple answers (in my case a 32 answer German Vocab test), the program doesn't mark the answers as right. Have tried many alternatives and it does work with single answers in a .txt document.

If someone has any knowledge and could help me, it would be much appreciated! :)

My .txt questions and answers are set out like this;

beliebt,popular

eng,narrow

Thanks for any help!! <3

Comment: What do you mean *"mark the answer as right"*?

Comment: So, you can set the answers for the quiz by typing in "O" but when you actually start the quiz (as you will see if you run it) the answers always mark themselves as wrong, even if you type in the correct answer.

Comment: The program as listed above works for me. There's some oddities about what you have to enter in order to continue entering values at the start (you need to type `"S"` again, not `"O"` as it prompts), but other than that it seems to work fine. I don't see any problems with the scoring. Can you show an example that doesn't get scored correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The program listed works for me as is (using Python 3.3.2). If you want it to work with multiple possible answers for one word (not sure if that's what you meant), you can use

```
if (answer in question[num][1:]):
```

instad of

```
if (answer == str(question[num][1])):
```

you might also want to strip any spaces from your sample answers:

```
for i in range(len(question)):
    for j in range(len(question[i])):
        question[i][j] = question[i][j].strip(' ')
```

use `lstrip` and `rstrip` if you want to have spaces inside the answer. 
Then you can add multiple answers just like this:

What is the translation for eng?
narrow, tight